# ExpandableListView child listeners hang

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have an `ExpandableListView` with multiple child's layouts that all share an `ImageView`, that represents a cancel action which collapses the corresponding `GroupView`...

the problem is that at random times **all Listeners** of a specific child view just **hang**, **they get fired** but i have to scroll the list or click on a different group to get them fired.

I'm sorry if it's a repeated question but i have spent a couple of hours and didn't find a solution, so please point me to the right direction.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out what the problem is.

actually I was using Google's ViewHolder design pattern  :

[Making ListView Scrolling Smooth](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html)

that was making the problem, sorry i don't have the time to investigate further of the issue and i dropped the ViewHolder, but I hope this will help someone else...